# Haskell: How to get element from a Maybe tuple

Tags: haskell

How do you extract the first element from a `Maybe` tuple? I have tried to use `fst` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: One thing to consider: What do you want to happen if there is no tuple (i.e. your `Maybe` value contains a `Nothing`)?

Comment: try `maybe undefined fst`, or `(fst <$>)`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `Maybe` is a functor, use `fmap` to lift `fst :: (a, b) -> a` to work with `Maybe (a,b)`.

```
> :t fmap fst
fmap fst :: Functor f => f (b, b1) -> f b
> fmap fst $ Just (3, 6)
Just 3
> fmap fst $ Nothing
Nothing
```

Of course, this returns a `Maybe a`, not an `a`, so you can use the `maybe` function to unpack the result (and provide a default value if the `Maybe (a, b)` is actually `Nothing`):

```
> import Data.Maybe
> maybe 0 fst (Just (3, 6))
3
> maybe 0 fst Nothing
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pattern match on `Maybe` value using `case`, for example:

```
case mbVal of
  Just x -> fst x
  Nothing -> ...
```

You can also use `fromJust` if you are sure the value is `Just`.

Finally, you can match the first element of a tuple right away:

```
case mbVal of
  Just (x,_) -> x
```